# On the number of subrings 

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Dear All,

It is well-known that a group is finite iff the number of its subgroups is finite. 
Is there any similar result for rings and subrings ?? (Clearly we have to distinguish two cases:

1. rings have identity and subrings have the same identity.
2. rings and subrings in general.

Comment: There is a third case, namely rings have to have identities but subrings don't necessarily share them. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01350707) says that an associative ring with a finite number of subrings is finite.

As pointed out below, the result does not hold for rings with a unit as witnessed by      $ \mathbb{Z}$ which has no proper subrings. Also, $ \mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ has two subrings including itself and $ \mathbb{Z}[1/6]$ has four. This shows that there is an infinite ring with $2^k$ subrings. What other examples are there which are commutative integral domains? I don't immediately see any. I think this is a ring with $3$ proper subrings: $ \mathbb{Z}[x]$ where $x^3=0\ne x^2$ and $7x=0.$ Of course $7$ can be replaced by any other prime.

Comment: The article seems to be referring to the second case. The result is clearly false in the first case, e.g. because $\mathbb{Z}$ has only one unital subring. 

Comment: There is also a lot of interesting information here: http://books.google.ie/books?hl=en&lr=&id=Bbk_fbDThzsC&oi=fnd&pg=PA173&ots=edUH_rQ4-3&sig=DxFICiN6_emgcTZw1AYVyCZV_pU&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false